# how to sort a list based on timestamp value of an object

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting, datetime

I have an object called `Orders`. One of the field in orders is `last_modified`. the format of this field is `01-JAN-16 02.15.49.086630 PM`

Then i have a list of these orders i.e., `orders_list`. How can I sort this list based on `last_modified` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a custom key. In this case, you need to convert your string field to `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_format = '%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p'

res = sorted(orders_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.last_modified, date_format))
```

See [Python's `strftime` directives](http://strftime.org/) to see how to construct `date_format`.